# Please explain me what is hapenning in line 3 of this code

Tags: perl, adjacency-matrix

Please explain me what is hapenning in line 3 of this code.

```
 for my $i (0 .. $dim) {
    for my $j (0 .. $dim) {
        $adj->[$i][$j] = $adj->[$i][$j] ? [$j] : [];
```

Comment: @Rene It would be incorrect to add closing brackets to the loops. This is all the code the OP posted.

Comment: @TLP it certainly did no harm.

Answer (score 3):

The code loops over two dimensions in an array reference `$adj`. Presumably, `$dim` is the dimension, and `$i` and `$j` iterate over a list of numbers from `0` to `$dim`, e.g. `0,1,2,3,4,5`.

For each combination of numbers, the value of that array element is checked for trueness, and is assigned a new value. If the value is false, it is assigned an array ref containing the index `$j`, otherwise an empty array ref `[]`.

The conditional operator is used here, with the basic syntax

```
CONDITION ? FOO : BAR
if CONDITION then FOO else BAR
```

Presumably, the array ref `$adj` is supposed to contain array references, which is why it can simply check for trueness as a shortcut for `defined $adj->[$i][$j]`.

Answer (score 2):

This is the *ternary operator*, aka *conditional operator*.

If `$adj->[$i][$j]` is 0 (or undefined) then `[]` is assigned to  `$adj->[$i][$j]`, in the other cases `$adj->[$i][$j]` is assigened to `$adj->[$i][$j]`.

[perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) has this quote:

> Ternary "?:" is the conditional operator, just as in C. It works much like an if-then-else. 
>   If the argument before the ? is true, the argument before the : is returned, otherwise the argument after the : is returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
    for my $i (0 .. $dim) {
      for my $j (0 .. $dim) {
```

Above for loops will itrate through the arry with dimension $dim x $dim

```
    $adj->[$i][$j] = $adj->[$i][$j] ? [$j] : [];
```

if $adj->[$i][$j] is zero, then assign [] to $adj->[$i][$j] else assign $j (column value)